# More efficient to make a power of 2 texture?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

I want to use the GPU on iOS to do some heavy calculations by putting my data into texture format and then running shaders.

The texture would be originally 640x480 (or a *Gaussian pyramid* of that), would it be better for performance if I expanded the texture to the next POT, 1024x1024, and then just read the results from the 640x480 section? Or would it just be a waste of memory, especially on a mobile device were it is so limited?

Comment: You should try to profile that performance on different devices yourself if possible, also it would be nice if you posted the result. As for the next POT you should know that width and height do not need to be equal so the next POT is 1024x512. BTW the memory increase on your sizes would be just over 60% and go up to about 2.1MB per POT texture, if you increase that to retina sizes the next POT will take just over 70% memory increase and up to 8.5MB. Not bad really unless you plan to have too many of them.

Comment: I plan to use 4-5 at the same time and the original size has a hard limit to 640x480, so it should be OK memory-wise. Didn't know you could use non-square POT.

Comment: Also just a thought: You might be able to use an atlas and have a single large texture containing all your textures. This way you should gain most from performance and memory consumption. But be careful to check the device texture size limit, some still have a limit of 1<<11 (2024) per texture dimension. Maybe pack 3 textures in one to have (640*3)x(480)...

Comment: That would be good. I'll start with the simplest case, then optimize.